# Proof inequality for summation

Tags: inequality, summation

I've been trying to proof the following:

Suppose $n \geq k,\,\,\,$ both $k, n \in N,\quad$
$\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{t=0}^{n-k}\frac{1}{n-k \choose t}}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{t=0}^{n-k}\frac{1}{{n-k \choose t}(n-t+1)}} \geq k+1$

Would you have any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to show that
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n-k}f(t)\ge\sum_{t=0}^{n-k}f(t)\frac{k+1}{n-t+1}$$
where $f(t)=1/{n-k\choose t}$, so it suffices to show that $n-t+1\ge k+1$ whenever $0\le t\le n-k$.